# oracle db - update table if join has no results

Tags: sql, oracle

In MS SQL I can do something like this:

```
if not exists (select * 
from table_1
inner join table_2 on table_1.id = table_2.id
where table_1.y = 200 and table_2.x =5)
begin
insert into table_1  values (200,1000)
insert into table_2 values (5,1000)
end;
```

Can I do something like this in  Oracle DB ?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be by using variables to check whatever you need and then decide what to do; for example:

```
declare
  vCheck   number;
begin
  select count(*)
  into vCheck
  from ...
  where ...;
  --
  if vCheck = 0 then
    insert ...;
    insert ...;
  end if;
end;
```

You can use one or more variables, depending on the check you need to do, and then adapt the `IF` condition to implement more complex logics.